# change margin color on custom modal

Tags: html, css, margin

I want to change the area( margin ) around my custom modal to this color  #494c4e54 . If the user clicks outside the modal it  closes, It would be nice if it wont be affected

CSS

```
.mojmodal
{
background: #e2e3e4;
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
display: none;
width: 350px;
height: 400px;
border-radius: 2px;
border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="mojmodal gorkaze">
<form name="vnos" method="post">
<div><legend>Prijava</legend>
<label>Uporabniško ime</label><br>
<input type="text" name="ime">
</div>
<div>
<br><label>Geslo</label>
<br><input type="password" name="geslo">
</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="zapomni"> Zapomni si me<br><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="tipkamodal">Prijava</button></div><div>
<a href="index.php?stran=registracija" style="text-decoration:none;color:gray;">Še nimate računa?</a>
</div></form>
Login();
</div>
```

[Here is a picture of the highlighted modal(click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j1Dg.png)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target#Pure-CSS_lightbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no margin color property.

To achieve this effect you'll need additional elements or pseudo elements.

J.D. commented on your question this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target#Pure-CSS_lightbox which should help you create the effect.

I'd also suggest you brush up on your CSS box model: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model